# Array of Dictionaries to Custom Class

Tags: arrays, dictionary, firebase, swift3, completionhandler

I have successfully pulled my Firebase data into a dictionary, but I'm having a tough time getting the values into my custom class.

To get my data from Firebase, I use this code:

```
func testing(completion: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> ()) {

    ref.child("dailyJobs").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let value = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
            completion(value as [String : Any])
            return
        }
        completion([:])
    })
}
```

When I call the function

```
testing { (dictionary) in
        print(dictionary)
    }
```

The dictionary I get back from Firebase is this (it's an array of dictionaries):

```
["name": custom chore list, "multiplier": 1, "assigned": none, "order": 0]
["name": bathrooms, "multiplier": 1, "assigned": none, "order": 1]
["name": laundry, "multiplier": 1, "assigned": none, "order": 2]
["name": living room, "multiplier": 1, "assigned": none, "order": 3]
["name": sweep & vacuum, "multiplier": 1, "assigned": sweep & vacuum, "order": 4]
["name": wipe table, "multiplier": 1, "assigned": none, "order": 5]
["name": counters, "multiplier": 1, "assigned": none, "order": 6]
["name": dishes, "multiplier": 1, "assigned": none, "order": 7]
["name": meal prep, "multiplier": 1, "assigned": none, "order": 8]
["name": feed pet / garbage, "multiplier": 1, "assigned": none, "order": 9]
```

My custom class is this:

```
class JobsAndHabits {

var name: String
var multiplier: Double
var assigned: String
var order: Int

init(jobName: String, jobMultiplier: Double, jobAssign: String, jobOrder: Int) {

    self.name = jobName
    self.multiplier = jobMultiplier
    self.assigned = jobAssign
    self.order = jobOrder
}
```

My code for parsing the `dictionary` is this:

```
testing { (dictionary) in
        for item in dictionary {
            print(item)
            let multiplier = dictionary["multiplier"] as! Double
            let name = dictionary["name"] as! String
            let assigned = dictionary["assigned"] as! String
            let order = dictionary["order"] as! Int

            let dailyJob = JobsAndHabits(jobName: name, jobMultiplier: multiplier, jobAssign: assigned, jobOrder: order)
            self.dailyJobs.append(dailyJob)
        }
        print(self.dailyJobs)
```

And I get back this:

```
[ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits, ToDo_App.JobsAndHabits]
```

It's 4 of each dictionary. Somehow my code is duplicating the array by 4x, and now my head hurts. I'm sure there is a simple solution to this.

**I've also tried:**

Putting all code in the original closure, like this:

```
    func loadExistingJobs(_ completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    ref.child("dailyJobs").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
            let multiplier = dictionary["multiplier"] as! Double
            let name = dictionary["name"] as! String
            let assigned = dictionary["assigned"] as! String
            let order = dictionary["order"] as! Int

            let dailyJob = JobsAndHabits(jobName: name, jobMultiplier: multiplier, jobAssign: assigned, jobOrder: order)
            self.dailyJobs.append(dailyJob)
            self.dailyJobs.sort(by: {$0.order < $1.order})

            self.jobsTableView.reloadData()
            completion()
        }
    })
```

But the `@escaping` closure doesn't run properly and my subsequent code doesn't get executed.

**TL;DR - I want to pull my data from Firebase and append it to my array.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check :

Your `dictionary` is `["name": custom chore list, "multiplier": 1, "assigned": none, "order": 0]` and you are writing loop for this. It has 4 keys, so it going loop for 4 times.

if your dictionary is like [String: Any], then you have to call like below :

```
testing { (dictionary) in
    let multiplier = Double(dictionary["multiplier"] as! Int)
    let name = dictionary["name"] as! String
    let assigned = dictionary["assigned"] as! String
    let order = dictionary["order"] as! Int

    let dailyJob = JobsAndHabits(jobName: name, jobMultiplier: multiplier, jobAssign: assigned, jobOrder: order)
    self.dailyJobs.append(dailyJob)

    print(self.dailyJobs)
})
```

if your dictionary is like [[String: Any]], then you have to call like below :

```
func testing(completion: @escaping ([[String : Any]]) -> ()) {
    let dictionary = [[String: Any]]
    ref.child("dailyJobs").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        for child in (snapshot?.children)! {
            let snap = child as! FDataSnapshot //each child is a snapshot
            if let value = snap.value as? [String : Any] {
                dictionary.append(value)   
            }
        }
        completion(dictionary)
    })
}

testing { (dictionary) in
    for item in dictionary {
        print(item)
        let multiplier = Double(item["multiplier"] as! Int)
        let name = item["name"] as! String
        let assigned = item["assigned"] as! String
        let order = item["order"] as! Int
        let dailyJob = JobsAndHabits(jobName: name, jobMultiplier: multiplier, jobAssign: assigned, jobOrder: order)
        self.dailyJobs.append(dailyJob)
        //            }
        print(self.dailyJobs)
    }
})
```

Comment: Yes, so how do I avoid that? I'm stumped. How do I get those **four** keys into my **one** class object?

Comment: Please check my code. Removed for loop. Now you will get correct results.

Comment: Crashed. `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional Value` on line 1: `let multiplier = dictionary...`

Comment: No. You are trying to convert Any to Double. So it is failing. Your `multiplier` is Double and its value in dictionary is Int.

Comment: Okay. Got that fixed. But now the data is still populating even after I call the code. When I print to the console `dailyJobs.count`, I get `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`. That means the code is still running. It should just be `10`. Is my completion handler wrong?

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I changed the conversion of `multiplier`

Comment: From completion Handler you are getting [String: Any]. If you get like [[String: Any]], this will be possible.

Comment: Can you give some example code of `[[String : Any]]`? I added it to the function: `func testing(completion: @escaping ([[String : Any]]) -> ()) {
        ref.child("dailyJobs").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let value = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
                completion([value as [String : Any]])
                return
            }
            completion([[:]])
        })
    }`, but now the call in `ViewDidLoad` is giving me errors: `cannot subscript a value of type [[String : Any]] with an index of type String`

Comment: Please check the updated answer. I added for [[String: Any]]

Comment: Not working. Getting error: `type (key: String, value: Any) has no subscript members`

Comment: I tried your updated code, and it's partially working. First, the data is complete **before** any new methods are called, so that's good. The completion handler is working correctly. However, when I run the `testing` method, it returns duplicates of the data. I'm now getting 20 jobs when it should be 10.

Comment: Hold the phone. Just kidding. I had a duplicate call to load the `dailyJobs`. So it's now working correctly, in that it returns 10 jobs. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can try this code and modify according to your need

```
class JobsAndHabits {

    var name: String
    var multiplier: Double
    var assigned: String
    var order: Int

    init(jobName: String, jobMultiplier: Double, jobAssign: String, jobOrder: Int) {

        self.name = jobName
        self.multiplier = jobMultiplier
        self.assigned = jobAssign
        self.order = jobOrder
    }
    class func getAllJobsAndHabbits(forUserID userID: String, completion: @escaping (JobsAndHabits) -> Swift.Void, failure: @escaping () -> ()) {
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            Database.database().reference().child("jobsAndHabits").child(userID).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                if snapshot.exists() {
                    let receivedMessage = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]

                    let name = receivedMessage["content"] as? String ?? ""
                    let multiplier = receivedMessage["multiplier"] as? Double ?? 0.0
                    let assigned = receivedMessage["assigned"] as? String ?? ""
                    let order = receivedMessage["order"] as? Int ?? 0
                    completion(JobsAndHabits(jobName: name, jobMultiplier: multiplier, jobAssign: assigned, jobOrder: order))
                } else {
                    failure()
                }
            })
        } else {
            failure()
        }
    }
}
```

Way to call and handle

```
class Test {
   let dailyJobs:[JobsAndHabits] = []

   JobsAndHabits.getAllJobsAndHabbits(forUserID: "12346", completion: {
       self.dailyJobs.append(dailyJob)
       self.dailyJobs.sort(by: {$0.order < $1.order})
    }) {
        //handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm.. `dailyJobs` is still loading asynchonously. I want to run code on the final call from the database, not incrementally. You see, I want to append another array based off of the `dailyJobs` list.